# How to run a long running processor async and use it from same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executors

Basically, we have a class called OfficeManger which acts as a driver  to connect to openoffice software, it needs to be connected all the time so we can use the converter to convert documents. We start the OpenOfficeProcess during the start of the web application, which starts fine. But looks like the executor which running in init() is on different thread and we couldn't able to get the running instance of OfficeManager. How to run in its own thread so that I can have this instance called from different class to use the converter method?

```
    OfficeDocumentConverter converter = OpenOfficeProcessor.getInstance().getDocumentConverter();

    converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile, pdf);
```

OpenOfficeProcessor

```
public class OpenOfficeProcessor  {

    private static final OpenOfficeProcessor INSTANCE = new OpenOfficeProcessor();
    static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private final OfficeManager officeManager;
    private final OfficeDocumentConverter documentConverter;

    public OpenOfficeProcessor(){
        DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration configuration = new DefaultOfficeManagerConfiguration();
        String homePath = ConfigurationManager.getApplicationProperty(ConfigurationManager.OPENOFFICE_HOME_PATH);
        if(homePath != null){
            configuration.setOfficeHome(homePath);
        } else {
            LOG.error("OpenOffice.home.path is not set in the properties file");
            new Throwable("Please set OPENOFFICE.HOME.PATH parameter in the properties file");
        }
        String port = ConfigurationManager.getApplicationProperty(ConfigurationManager.OPENOFFICE_LISTENER_PORT);
        if( port != null){
            configuration.setPortNumber(Integer.parseInt(port));
        }else {
            LOG.error("openoffice.listener.port is not set in the properties file");
        }
        String executionTimeout = ConfigurationManager.getApplicationProperty(ConfigurationManager.OPENOFFICE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT);
        if(executionTimeout != null){
            configuration.setTaskExecutionTimeout(Long.parseLong(executionTimeout));
        }
        String pipeNames = ConfigurationManager.getApplicationProperty(ConfigurationManager.OPENOFFICE_PIPES_NAMES);
        if(ConfigurationManager.getApplicationProperty(ConfigurationManager.OPENOFFICE_PIPES_NAMES)!= null){
            configuration.setPipeNames(pipeNames);
        }

        officeManager = configuration.buildOfficeManager();
        documentConverter = new OfficeDocumentConverter(officeManager);
    }
    public static OpenOfficeProcessor getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }


    protected static void init() {
        LOG.debug("Starting the open office listener...");
        executor.submit(new Callable(){

            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                OpenOfficeProcessor.getInstance().officeManager.start();
                return null;
            }
        });

    }

    protected static void destroy() {
        LOG.debug("Stopping the open office listener...");
        OpenOfficeProcessor.getInstance().officeManager.stop();
    }

    public OfficeManager getOfficeManager() {
        return officeManager;
    }

    public OfficeDocumentConverter getDocumentConverter() {
        return documentConverter;
    }

}
```

OfficeManager

```
public interface OfficeManager {

    void execute(OfficeTask task) throws OfficeException;

    void start() throws OfficeException;

    void stop() throws OfficeException;

    boolean isRunning();
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here.  What does `start()` do?  Does that spawn another thread?  Does the `OfficeManager` code run inside of `start()`?  Right now it looks to me like you call `start()` but there is nothing that is running the manager code itself?  You should do some editing and think about how this project reads to someone who has no experience with it.

Comment: What is exactly the issue, the code does not compile?

Comment: If i use OfficeManager.start() directly, then i can use documentConverter for conversion. But now since i started OfficeManager using executor i couldn't use the documentConverter as it tells me that OfficeManager is not started.